# Image not rendering on iOS Safari Webkit while setting height / width as auto

Tags: ios, webview, safari

I'm trying to run the following code on iOS simulator (WebView inside a mobile app):

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <img src="https://files.geektime.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/GettyImages-139807042-1513776960-1024x680.jpg" alt="alt" style="width: 375px; height:auto;">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, I'm getting an empty result.

On another browsers & mobile browsers it works as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think it's because of https. you can try showing an image from from a http protocol and see if it works, you may do some configuration to get this working

Comment: @avishay-bassa : Tested your html its loading the image fine for me